How to deal with error: Both 'ContentTemplate' and 'ContentTemplateSelector' are set; 'ContentTemplateSelector' will be ignored
I have created a DataGrid in WPF that has Combobox column with templated content (to show items inside embedded combobox with a certain color). Here is actual code:
 <DataGrid x:Name="WorkerTasksDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" 
           Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource persons}}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
           IsReadOnly="False">
     <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43044022/5128696 -->            
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding Path=StartDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Date" Binding="{Binding Path=EndDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
         <!-- Here will be converter with parameter -->
         <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702737/how-to-pass-specific-value-to-the-converter-parameter -->
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours" Binding="{Binding Path=CalculatedTime}" IsReadOnly="True" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project" Binding="{Binding Path=Project}"  />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task" Binding="{Binding Path=Task}"  />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remark" Binding="{Binding Path=Remark}"  />
         <!-- how to use combobox in table https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996663/5128696 -->
         <!-- how to style combobox items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27963452/5128696 -->
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Target Company, Customer, Project" x:Name="TargetCompanyCol" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=TargetCompanyColored}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:WorkerAndTasksVM.ChooseCompanyItemsColored}}" DisplayMemberPath="displayName"  >
             <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                     <!-- 'Both ContentTemplate and ContentTemplateSelector are set' error happens when I click on Combobox https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416321/5128696 -->
                     <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                 <Label Name="DT_ListLabel" Content="{Binding displayName}" Background="{Binding displayColor}" Margin="0"/>
                             </DataTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>
             </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
         </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>

     <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
<!-- that thing is complicated and not related to question -->
     </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

 </DataGrid>

When I click on Combobox and unravel a list of items, a 'Both ContentTemplate and ContentTemplateSelector are set' error happens. Here is a full text:

System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : Both 'ContentTemplate' and 'ContentTemplateSelector' are set;  'ContentTemplateSelector' will be ignored. ComboBoxItem:'ComboBoxItem' (Name='')

I do not specify ContentTemplateSelector in code!
It repeats the number of times equal to number of times in combobox list. I tried to set ItemTemplateSelector="{x:Null}" inside that label in DataTemplate (DT_ListLabel), like I have seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416321/5128696 but it did not help (I do not have a treeview, but actually a DataGrid and Combobox). User can select items in combobox, color shows too, but I still get those errors. How do I solve that?

I managed to make it work. Apparently, DisplayMemberPath contradicts ItemTemplate. This issue is more related to Combobox (or any other Control), rather than Data Grid and Combobox Column. This question was insightful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656372 . So I removed that declaration.
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Target Company, Customer, Project" x:Name="TargetCompanyCol" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=TargetCompanyColored}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:WorkerAndTasksVM.ChooseCompanyItemsColored}}"  >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Name="DT_ListLabel" Content="{Binding displayName}" Background="{Binding displayColor}" Margin="0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>

I also had to define toString method for a class that holds displayColor and displayName because after selecting of item using combobox it showed class name instead of displayName. That method returns displayName to make display more user-friendly
